# ¿Qué posibilidades de búsqueda tiene el diccionario de la RAE? || What searching capabilities does RAE's dictionary have?

Tags: rae, dle

¿Cuáles son las posibilidades de búsqueda del [diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DgIqVCc)? ¿Puede hacer algún otro tipo de consultas además de la búsqueda por palabras?

---

What are the searching capabilities of the dictionary edited by the *Real Academia Española*? Can you make any other queries besides the word search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí. Aunque no lo parezca, lo que hay a la izquierda del recuadro de búsqueda es un desplegable con las siguientes opciones:

[image: Opciones de búsqueda del DLE]

- **Búsqueda por palabras:** hace una búsqueda laxa. Esto quiere decir que puede buscar tiempos verbales o formas en femenino y plural. Si buscas "raquetas" automáticamente te mostrará el artículo para "raqueta". Si buscas "comía" automáticamente te dirigirá al artículo para "comer". Si buscas "salido" te mostrará como opciones la propia palabra "salido" o el verbo "salir".
  La búsqueda por palabras permite además el autocompletado en el recuadro de búsqueda, no solo de los lemas simples del diccionario, sino de expresiones más complejas. Así, si se buscan varias palabras aparecerán todas las expresiones que las contengan sin importar el orden (la búsqueda de "pasado toro" hace que en el autocompletado aparezca "a toro pasado").
  Nótese que, aunque la búsqueda sea laxa en el sentido especificado, sí que distingue entre las versiones con y sin tilde de las vocales. Así, si se busca "dia" (sin tilde) no redirige al artículo para "día", sino al del prefijo "dia-".
- Búsqueda por lemas:

  - **Exacta:** hace una búsqueda exacta, sin importar si la palabra es un derivado de otra. Así, si en este caso buscas "salido" te dirigirá automáticamente al artículo para "salido".
  - **Empieza por:** muestra una lista de términos que comienzan por el criterio de búsqueda, o un artículo si solo hay un resultado. Así, si se busca "cabale" mostrará automáticamente el artículo "cabalero", mientras que si se busca "cabal" mostrará una lista de resultados.
  - **Termina en:** igual que el caso anterior, pero teniendo en cuenta el final de la palabra. Así, si se busca "lol" mostrará automáticamente el artículo "salol", mientras que buscando "ol" mostrará todas las palabras que acaben de esa forma.
  - **Contiene:** igual que el caso anterior, pero buscando el término de búsqueda en cualquier posición de la palabra. Así, si se busca "axan" mostrará el artículo de "laxante", mientras que si se busca "axa" mostrará una lista de resultados.
- **Anagramas:** busca todas las palabras que contengan todas las letras del término de búsqueda, en cualquier orden, incluyendo formas derivadas y conjugaciones y sin importar las tildes. Así, si se busca "carlos", entre los resultados aparece "claros" (redirige al artículo de "claro") y "clorás" (del artículo para el verbo "clorar").
- **Aleatoria:** desactiva el recuadro del término de búsqueda y simplemente muestra el artículo de una palabra cualquiera del diccionario.

Por último, como atajo si tienes dudas sobre cualquier palabra de la definición que estés viendo, puedes pulsar sobre la misma para acceder a su propia definición.

Comment: Además, puedes hacer click en cualquier palabra de una definición y te redirige a su definición.

Comment: @MikMik ¡gracias! Lo añado a la respuesta. :-)

Comment: I think it is true that it distinguishes between a letter and the same letter with an accent so that for example if I type dia I do not get directed to the Spanish word for day. If I am correct and not just suffering from some mental block perhaps you could add that as it does not come over to me from your answer.

Comment: @mdewey es cierto, las búsquedas distinguen entre vocales con y sin tilde, es la búsqueda de anagramas la única que no hace esa distinción. Añadido queda, y añado además la opción del autocompletado en la búsqueda por palabras.